# Bottom div does not reposition on browser resize

Tags: html, css

The bottom div, `.lower` does not re-position itself to the bottom of the page when the screen is resized. Is this because of `position:absolute;`?

https://jsfiddle.net/q1p4dp4b/

```
#lower {    
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;}
```

[image]

*EDIT* added `position:fixed;` but text gets layered on

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You want `position: fixed`. This makes it stick to the bottom of your viewport and stay there when you scroll.

Comment: Hm. The text gets layered on top of though at the bottom. *added pic to OP*

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: If you mean that you cannot scroll to see the last line of text then you could add a margin-bottom to the content that is at least as tall as the fixed div.